# How to add a Invalid Html values to XML element in C#?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xmlelement

```
<div data-type="twitter" data-handle="englandcricket" data-handlename="England <hlt1>Cricket</hlt1>"  data-status="Record-breaker"
```

this is values I am trying to add to xmlelement, getting an error in tag `<hlt1>`

Can somebody help in this issue?

Comment: I think you mean "add text containing HTML elements to a `data-` attrribute" - if so, just HTML-encode them: `data-handlename="England &lt;hlt1&gt;Cricket&lt;/hlt1&gt;"`

Comment: Issue is the angle brackets.  Use : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: You cannot have `<` in an attribute value.  XML with `<` in an attribute value would be **malformed**.  From the [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax): *The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped...*.

Comment: For confirmation, try uploading `<div data-handlename="England <hlt1>Cricket</hlt1>" />` to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/.  You will get an error *The value of attribute "data-handlename" associated with an element type "div" must not contain the '<' character.*  It needs to be `data-handlename="England &lt;hlt1&gt;Cricket&lt;/hlt1&gt;"` as mentioned above.

Comment: But how exactly are you getting the error?  Can you share a [mcve] showing the code that throws the error?